# fos_rest.decoder.jsontoform does not work with Symfony 4 FOS Rest Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I try to send boolean value to api endpoint and FOS rest bundle return:

```
"foo": {
      "errors": [
         "This value should not be blank."
       ]
},
```

My FOS Rest bundle config:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    body_listener:
        enabled: true
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.jsontoform
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    format_listener:
        enabled:              true
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api2', priorities: [ 'json', 'xml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        formats:
            json: true
    zone:
        - { path: ^/api2/* }
```

My form field:

```
->add('foo', CheckboxType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
        ])
```

And payload:

```
 {
     "foo": false
 }
```

Anyone have idea why it does not work?

Comment: Di you try to set `foo` like this: `"foo": 0`?

Comment: I have just added `new NotBlank(['allowNull' => true]),` and it still does not work